# Increment a Pandas Dataframe Column Based on Date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe of dates on which I want to increment a column value, what I call "mid-month", by 1 **every 14th of the month**, like:

```
date        day_of_month mid_month_id
2004-05-12            12            5
2004-05-13            13            5
2004-05-14            14            6
2004-05-15            15            6
```

till... the end of time (let's put it on 2020-12-31).

But what I have for now is:

```
date        day_of_month  mid_month_id
2004-05-12            12  xxx
2004-05-13            13  xxx
2004-05-14            14  xxx
2004-05-15            15  xxx
```

I subsetted and applied:

```
df_test = df.loc[:,['day_of_month', 'mid_month_id']]

# Let's start at mid_month_id 7
m = 7


for i, row in df_test.iterrows():
    if df_test.loc[i, 'day_of_month'] < 14 and df_test.loc[i, 'mid_month_id'] == "xxx":
        df_test.loc[i, 'mid_month_id'] = m;
    if df_test.loc[i, 'day_of_month'] >= 14 and df_test.loc[i, 'mid_month_id'] == "xxx":
        df_test.loc[i, 'mid_month_id'] = m + 1;
    m = m + 1

df_test
```

It returned an increment from a day to the next one, instead.

Then, I tried without the *m = m + 1*, so the values were 7 and 8 till the end.

A bit challenging, at least, for me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this in your dataset, using `cumsum`.

```
m=7
df_test['mid_month_id'] = m+(df.day_of_month == 14).cumsum()

print(m + (df.day_of_month == 14).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
0    7
1    7
2    8
3    8
4    8
5    8
6    9
7    9
Name: day_of_month, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you Scott for this numpy solution. It's so simple. Best!